# chrome.tabs.sendMessageの返り値がundefinedになる

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

chromeで以下の処理を行うアドオンを作成しようとしています。

1. popup.htmlにあるテキストエリアに文字列を入力(改行区切りで複数入力可)し、送信ボタンを押下
2. popup.jsでボタン押下をキャッチし、フォームに入力された値を配列にしてcontent.jsに渡す
3. content.jsでアクティブタブ内にあるテーブルの3列目を検索し、入力された文字列を一致するものを探す
4. 検索終了後、結果をアラートで表示

各ファイルのコードは以下の通りです。

- manifest.json

  ```
   {
     "name": "test",
     "version": "0.0.2",
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "description": "test",
     "icons": {
             "16": "img/icon_16.png"
           },
     "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "img/icon_16.png",
       "default_title": "test",
       "default_popup" : "popup.html"  
     },
     "content_scripts": [
       {
         "matches": ["https://*/*"],
         "js": ["js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "js/content.js"],
         "run_at": "document_end"
       }
     ],
     "permissions": [
       "tabs"
     ]
   }
  ```
- popup.js

  ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tab) {
       $('#do_action').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var list = "";

         list = $("[name='list']").val();
         if(list == ""){
           alert("文字をテキストエリアに入れてください。");
           return false;
         }

         var list_array = list.split("\n");

         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {list: list_array}, function(response){
           alert(response.result);
         });
       });
     });
   });
  ```
- content.js

  ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     var hit_datas = [];
     var send_mes = "";
     $.each(request.list, function() {
       var search_value = this;
       $('tr').each(function(){
         if($('td',this).eq(2).text() == search_value){
             hit_datas.push(search_value + "が見つかりました。");
           }
         }
       });
     });

     if(hit_datas.length != 0){
       send_mes = hit_datas.join("\n");
     }else{
       send_mes = "一致する情報は有りませんでした。";
     }
     sendResponse({result: send_mes});
   });
  ```

popup.htmlにはdo_actionというidを振ったボタンと、listという名前を付けたテキストエリア、そしてpopup.jsを読み込む記述が書いてあります。

上記の内容で実行すると、popup.jsの『alert(response.result);』の部分で
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
というエラーが発生してしまいます。

色々調べてみたのですが、自力で解決できませんでした。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

> 上記の内容で実行すると、popup.jsの『alert(response.result);』の部分で
>   extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
>   というエラーが発生してしまいます。

引数なしでコールバック関数が呼び出される（つまり、 response 引数値が `undefined` になる）ということは、何かしらのエラーが発生していることを示しています。その原因は、 `chrome.runtime.lastError` に入っているはずなので、その lastError の内容を確認してみてください。原因がわかると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。()

Comment: すみません、途中で送信してしまいました。ここ、回答がついてもメールで通知されないんですね……。反応が遅れてすみません。コードを変更せずに翌日動かしたら問題なく処理が進んだので、結局何が原因だったのか分からずじまいでした。chrome.runtime.lastErrorの存在を知らなかったので、今後はそれを使ってみたいと思います。